# COM control in VB6: Make a container out of the control

Tags: c#, com, vb6, containers

I have a c# control that I use inside of VB6, which is basically a panel with rounded corners. I'd like to know if there is a way to make that control a container, sort of like a Frame is a container. Basically I want to be able to place things inside it so they all move together, and most importantly place things *In Front* of it.

Right now if I place, say, a label or a command on top of it, it goes behind my COM control and using `Bring to Front` and `Send to Back` does nothing.

Do I need to declare it as a container in vb6? Does the code have to come from c#?

**Edit:**

I have signed an NDA so I can't post the whole code here, but I'll post some and explain some.

```
public class AzPanel : Panel
{
    protected const int BORDER_WIDTH = 3;
    protected int BORDER_RADIUS = 4;
    private object _lock = new object();
    private bool regionNeedsRefresh = false;

    public AzPanel() : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(
          ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
          ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        base.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.BorderColor = Color.DarkRed;
        this.ContentColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        base.Padding = new Padding(3, 3, 4, 4);
    }
}
```

There's some other stuff to define a region with rounded corners as well, but it's basically just a panel. I have a class that extends AzPanel, AzPanelCOM with the following attributes:

```
[Guid("...")]
[ProgId...]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComdefaultInterface...]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
```

As well as an interface, IAzPanelCOM, to expose it to VB6.

```
[Guid("...")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IAzPanelCOM
{
    void DesignTimeReload();
    //some other things
}
```

On build I use "regasm.exe" to create a type library (tlb) that I import in VB6 on a virtual machine running Windows xp and vs2010 (.net framework 4.0).

I can then instantiate AzPanels, resize them and move them even at design time, and I can add commands (buttons) to them with no problems. When it comes to shapes or labels, however, they seem to appear behind the panel and I can't bring them to the front.

Comment: So I've got most of it working, but it seems like it was the easy part. I'm able to make it so my panel is a container, but placing shapes, lines and label "inside" places them behind my control. They all move with the control, but are invisible. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd love to help you debug but I have no idea what your code looks like...

Comment: Just to double check, you are using a .net control in VB6 via COM.  A quick search revealed this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/1beac437-b5d8-42c9-b226-45688c6d5962

tl;dr: The control is exposed as a common control, but doesn't implement the same interfaces, so you can't add controls to it.

Comment: @tijizor You can't use windowless controls (shape, label, et.c) with a .NET container component. However, you could use a VB windowed control, e.g. Frame (no border) or Picture Box inside the .NET component, into which you place those windowless controls.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: I think you should add that as answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per @MarkBertenshaw Comment

> You can't use windowless controls (shape, label, et.c) with a .NET container component. However, you could use a VB windowed control, e.g. Frame (no border) or Picture Box inside the .NET component, into which you place those windowless controls